# Find average of last X records for every person

Tags: mysql

I have a table which stores every score from every player. I want to take out the last 3 (or less) and display the average.

Example:

```
TABLE log
time  p_id  score
----  ----  -----
12:00 0     10
14:23 0     25
14:25 1     30
16:27 0     70
17:00 0     80
```

Now I want to find the average of all players' last 3 entries...

Result:

```
p_id  avg
----  ---
0     58
1     30
```

How should I proceed?

*Edit in 2020*: I was suddenly reminded of this question because of a notification of a new answer, and I see that I also have a neglected answer since back in 2010 that I should've given some feedback on.

While I'm not in dire need of a solution here (I believe I ended up with a loop, sending queries once for every player. It worked fine in my case with 50 players total), here is a sqlfiddle I set up to test the different solutions to be able to give feedback. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d7ca5b

Comment: I've tried a number of things and got nowhere. While doing this, I noticed some alarming things coming out of MySQL...`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM log LIMIT 3;` produces an answer of 5. Surely that can't be right? It appears the aggregations are ignoring the LIMIT clause, so 'SELECT AVG(score) FROM log WHERE p_id = 0 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 3;` produces an average of 46.25 not 58.333 as I would expect.

Comment: Adding to Brian Hooper's commetns, Probably you need to join on a subquery which returns those last 3 rows and then use an aggregate function on that result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`limit` will not work, use `row_number()` instead (mysql)

```
SELECT p_id, AVG(score) 
FROM (
    SELECT p_id, score, time
    FROM (
        SELECT p_id, score, time
        , row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY p_id ORDER BY time DESC) AS rn
        FROM log
    ) AS sub
    WHERE rn < 4
) AS dt
GROUP BY p_id
ORDER BY p_id
```

Comment: This works! It wouldn't have worked back in 2010 when I asked the question, but since row_number() was introduced in MySql 8.0 it is now possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT p_id, avg(score) as avg_score
FROM (
  SELECT p_id, score FROM log ORDER BY time LIMIT 3
)
GROUP BY p_id
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry about necro-commenting... When running this in sqlfiddle ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d7ca5b/2 ) it will only take the last 3 results total, not each players last 3 results.

Answer (score 1):

For versions of MySql prior to 8.0, without window functions, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select l.p_id, round(avg(l.score), 0) avg
from log l
where (select count(*) from log where p_id = l.p_id and time >= l.time) <= 3
group by l.p_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=e3525c8810b86f9c613002184a73e44d).
Results:

```
> p_id | avg
> ---: | --:
>    0 |  58
>    1 |  30
```